# How do I remove a (sub) layout item from QVBoxLayout?

Tags: qt

I found a lot of answers about removing widget from QVBoxLayout.

But I didn't find out any answer about removing a layout. I know I can put my sub-layout into a QWidget. I just want to know something more.

```
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
item_in_layout = create_layout()
layout.addLayout(item_in_layout)
# Remove?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [removeItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#removeItem) with the pointer to the layout you want to remove.

Comment: This doesn't work in case this layout has items inside it and you don't take care of them.

Comment: I am looking for a clean solution, but have the same problem. The child widgets are still there. Anyone find a proper solution to this?

Comment: @zalavari The "problem" is that layouts are not part of the parent-child relationship (they only intermediate it), so if you want to remove the contents too, it can be done by adding a QWidget inside the main layout and add the removable layout into widget. Obviously to remove, you remove/delete the QWidget.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QLayout::itemAt` to obtain the corresponding layout item and `QLayout::removeItem` to remove it.