# Delete all children from QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt

I have a [QVBoxLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qvboxlayout.html) inside a [scrollArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qscrollarea.html). I dynamically add [QFormLayout](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qformlayout.html)s.

```
widgetTreeStruct* tree = new widgetTreeStruct(QString::number(numberOfGraphs)); 
QFormLayout* layout = tree->getTree(); // get QFormLayout
ui->verticalLayout_2->addLayout(layout); //add to the vertical layout
```

At one point I need to remove all the added [QFormLayouts](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qformlayout.html) from the [QVBoxLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qvboxlayout.html).

I tried several ways to do this.

1. Using qDeleteAll()

> `qDeleteAll(ui->verticalLayout_2->children());`

2.delete item one by one

```
QLayoutItem* child;
          while((child = ui->verticalLayout_2->takeAt(0)) != 0)
          {
              if(child->widget() != 0)
              {
                  delete child->widget();
              }

              delete child;
          }
```

But nothing happened. Only thing is when I try to add items to QVBoxLayout again new items are added on top of the previously added items.

[image: After added items to QVBoxLayout]

I sense that I have to redraw, repaint, update, refresh or something. I tried `ui->verticalLayout_2->update();` but didn't work for me.

So, What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recursively deleted all the children and it worked for me.

This is my code.

```
void Widget::remove(QLayout* layout)
{
    QLayoutItem* child;
    while(layout->count()!=0)
    {
        child = layout->takeAt(0);
        if(child->layout() != 0)
        {
            remove(child->layout());
        }
        else if(child->widget() != 0)
        {
            delete child->widget();
        }

        delete child;
    }
}

remove(ui->verticalLayout_2);
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025152/how-do-i-remove-a-sub-layout-item-from-qvboxlayout. Remove seems the right method

Answer (score 2):

Probably the widgets's parent is the containing *widget*, not their layout (what is passed to their constructors for the `parent` parameter?).

Maybe [`QObject::dumpObjectTree()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#dumpObjectTree) can help you to understand the parent-child relationships.

What happens with your approach 2 (which does not rely on the widgets being children in the `QObject`-sense of the layout) is that it removes all items from the layout with the `takeAt()` method but deletes none of them: The children of your toplevel `QVBoxLayout` are the `QFormLayout`s, so calling `widget()` on their `QLayoutItems` returns `0`. Just use `delete child` unconditionally to delete the child `QLayout`s. However, this still does not delete the child *widgets*. You could either recursively call `takeAt()` on the child layouts or delete all children of the parent widget (your `QScrollArea`) or keep a list of widgets and/or layouts yourself.

Comment: When I try delete all the children from `QVBoxLayout` and add another widget to `QVBoxLayout` again, I can see the new widget appears on top of the previous widgets. That shows widgets are actually children of `QVBobLayout` and actually they have been deleted. Right? But only thing is they need to clear or hide from the window. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: They aren't deleted, only removed from the layout because of your use of `widget()`. See my edit above.